# How to write letters with a slash on it?

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I write letters like the following in mathjax?

[image]

Comment: You can also use [this](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to look for individual symbols. Some preset "not" type symbols are already there.

Comment: The syntax "\require{cancel} \cancel {a+b}" works.  You only need to use the "require" command once per session.  See [the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/13183#13183)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If there exists a specific symbol, you should use that: such as `\notin` $\notin$, `\neq` $\neq$, `\nmid` $\nmid$.

Alternatively, you can use `\not`. For example, `\not\in` $\not\in$, `\not=` $\not=$, `\not\mid` $\not\mid$, `\not\equiv` $\not\equiv$.

I will quote from "[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020)" - [current revision](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5020/118): "You can use `\not` to put a slash through almost anything: `\not\lt` $\not\lt$ but it often looks bad."

Comment: `\not\exists` looks OK: $\not\exists$, but `\not\forall` doesn't: $\not\forall$.

Comment: I wonder if `\not\in` isn't now special-cased to expand to `\notin`.  I can remember earlier times when it looked substantially worse than `\notin`.  Certainly `\not\mid` must be doing that.

Answer (score 2):

@MartinSleziak has already mentioned almost everything important, so I would only mention a few alternatives and additional information.

For a character/symbol (which I will write as `[symbol]`) you don't necessarily have to write `\not[symbol]`. Alternatively, you can also use `\not{[symbol]}` (both look the same, but it's useless if you use it quite often in one line or it's not a $\LaTeX$ command that you have to write with `\`. E.g. `\not{a}` is $\not{a}$.

Unfortunately, some $\LaTeX$ symbols cannot be written correctly with `\not{[symbol]}` and do not have `\not[...]` in their names. Instead they use `\n[...]`. E.g. `\nsupseteqq` is $\nsupseteqq$, but `\notsupseteqq` does not exist and `\nsupseteqq` ($\not{\supseteqq}$) looks much different. For some symbols even this doesn't work. E.g. you have to write `\varnothing` for $\varnothing$.

If you don't like any of the variants, you can also use `\![...]\! /` Use as an alternative. `\!` is a kind of negative line spacing, which moves your text after it (here the `/`) further into the character before it. E.g. `x \!\! /` is $x \!\! /\!$, `x \!\!\! /` is $x \!\!\! /$, `x \!\!\!\! /` is $x \!\!\!\! /\,$ and `\not{x}` is $\not{x}$. The same goes for `\backslash` ($\backslash$) or `\setminus` ($\setminus$). With this you can also get other symbols like $\therefore \!\! \because$ (`\therefore \!\! \because`).

Comment: +1 : kudos for mentioning negative line spacing.